# About the probability on infinite trials

Tags: probability

Assume that you are locked inside a room, the only way of getting out is to press a button. Each time you press the button, you have some chance of getting out (success). You are allowed to press as many times as you want.

Let the probability of success on the nth trial (given you failed n-1 trials) be $f_n$. If for some $0<a\leq1,f_n=a$, then the probability of getting out $\rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

If for some $0\leq a<1,f_n=a^n$, then you might not be able to get out even if you pressed for infinite many times. (This can be proven easily)

What about $f_n=\frac{1}{2n}$? $\frac{1}{2n^2}$? etc. What are the conditions for $f_n$, so  that the probability of getting out $\rightarrow 1$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: The probability to stay locked if $\prod_n(1-f_n)$. Then the probability of succes is $1 - \prod_n(1-f_n)$

Comment: Given $0\le f_n\le 1$ it follows that $\prod(1-f_n)>0$ if and only if $\sum f_n<\infty$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry, I don't understand. For example, if $f_3=1$ and then $f_n = 0$, the probality of stay locked is equal to 0 ... and the sum is less than $\infty$

Comment: I meant $0<f_n<1$, sorry